# Android and Facebook: How to get picture of logged in User

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, image

I use the official Facebook SDK in my Android Application. After the user logs in, I can get the uid and the name of the facebook user like so:

```
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
// ... user logs in ...
//String jsonUser = mFacebook.request("me/picture"); // throws error
String jsonUser = mFacebook.request("me");
JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
String facebookId = obj.optString("id");
String name = obj.optString("name");
```

I also know that the I can access the profile picture with those links:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<facebookId>/picture 
https://graph.facebook.com/<facebookId>/picture?type=large
```

I would love to use this code to geht the profile picture:

```
public static Drawable getPictureForFacebookId(String facebookId) {

    Drawable picture = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId + "/picture").openStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {        
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;

    }
    picture = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "facebook-pictures");

    return picture;
}
```

But it just wont work. I always get the following error:

```
SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

And I cant solve this issue. It seems to be rather complicated(look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117896/problems-with-httpclient-and-selfsigned-certificates) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/android-trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)). So what other options are there to get the picture of a facebook user that successfully logged into my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

request("me/picture") throws an error because the server returns a 302 (redirect to the image url) and the facebook sdk does not handle this.

Answer (score 22):

```
ImageView user_picture;
 userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
 userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

where ID is ur profile ID...

Comment: nice and straight way but i would say id even can be name of the user like "parag.chauhan"

Comment: thts true..but this cant be use for each user, as thr could be so many user of same name...

Comment: Not working for higher version ...This works like charm in lower version but not in higher version. What should I do for that?

Comment: The current URL is a 302 redirect, get the 302 location and a second request to get the image. This helped me out [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/)

Answer (score 9):

I also had that problem some time ago. What I did was download the picture using an async task, and then set an ImageView with the image just downloaded. I will paste the code snippet:

```
ImageView fbUserAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fb_user_avatar);

private synchronized void downloadAvatar() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL fbAvatarUrl = null;
            Bitmap fbAvatarBitmap = null;
            try {
                fbAvatarUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+USER_ID+"/picture");
                fbAvatarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fbAvatarUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fbAvatarBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            fbUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}
```

This code works for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: This code just couldn't work for you because it didn't compiled. `AsyncTask` takes 3 parameters and not 1 (so you can't use `AsyncTask<Bitmap>`, but `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>`). Also it doesn't have `taskComplete` method, but have `onPostExecute` instead. I edited your code to make it compilable.

Comment: I use my own AsyncTask with only one parameter, so yes, it was working. Anyway, thanks for editing...

Answer (score 5):

You can request a direct URl which contains your Access token:

```
URL MyProfilePicURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=normal&method=GET&access_token="+ Access_token );
```

Then get a decoded BitMap and assign it to image view:

```
Bitmap MyprofPicBitMap = null;
try {
    MyprofPicBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MyProfilePicURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

MyProfilePicImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

Answer (score 2):

For displaying profile pic in your app, use `ProfilePictureView` from Facebook SDK.

Refer This

Just call `setProfileId(String profileId)` on it.

It will take care of displaying the image.

Answer (score 1):

Add one line of code and that will be resolved.

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, (*usuario is a GraphUser*):

```
ProfilePictureView p;
p = (ProfilePictureView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fotoPerfil);
p.setProfileId(usuario.getId());
```

and xml markup:

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    facebook:preset_size="normal"/>
```