# How to load user image from facebook?

Tags: android

How would i go about loading a use's image into a application? I already know how to use sso and authentication and get user info and other things. Just dont know how to retreive the profile picture.

How would i go about doing thiEDIT: I am using easy facebook sdk. That question didnt really anwser my question.

Comment: You should search on SO before posting a question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461150/android-and-facebook-how-to-get-picture-of-logged-in-user

Comment: Did you look at the answers? It appears there is code directly applicable to your question...

Comment: could you post what it is and exaplin it in a answer? I'll give you credit for it and a vote up.