# Java/Android: Incorrect number of arguments for type AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-asynctask

I think there's something wrong with this code. Can someone please check if there are any mistakes in the code?

```
        ImageView userPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPicture);

    private synchronized void downloadAvatar(){
        AsyncTask <Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask <Bitmap> (){

            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                //Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public Bitmap doInBackground() {
                URL fbAvatarUrl = null;
                Bitmap fbAvatarBitmap = null;
                try {
                    fbAvatarUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture");
                    fbAvatarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fbAvatarUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return fbAvatarBitmap;
            }

            @Override
            public void taskComplete(Bitmap result) {
                fbUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the row with this code:

```
AsyncTask <Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask <Bitmap> ()
```

The error message is:

> Incorrect number of arguments for type AsyncTask; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Comment: "I get an error reading the question"

Comment: Please give us what error you get on the specified row. It would make life so much easier trying to understand the problem. Also, when asking this type of questions, please try to submit the least amount of code needed to understand the purpose. It is also great if it compiles..

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Incorrect number of arguments for type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Bitmap> ProfileActivity.java /code/src/com/marakana/tutomaps line 203 Java Problem

Answer (score 4):

`AsyncTask` takes three arguments: Params, Progress and Result. It should probably be `AsyncTask< Bitmap, Void, Void >` in your case; and `doInBackground` should take a `Bitmap... args`.

Comment: I copied the answer from this question and it doesn't work. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461150/android-and-facebook-how-to-get-picture-of-logged-in-user" I getting errorDescription Resource Path Location Type
Incorrect number of arguments for type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Bitmap> ProfileActivity.java /code/src/com/marakana/tutomaps line 203 Java Problem

Comment: @PatrikAxelsson The code in [the answer you used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461736/648313) contained an error. I have just edited it to make it compilable and left the comment which describes the reason of errors.