# How to post to a user's wall at a later date

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm trying to figure out how, after a user has opted into my Facebook Application, to retain their credentials so as to post to their wall at a later time.  I see apps doing this all the time, but I'm unclear where/how they store the user's login (I'm guessing they're not actually holding on to U/P but rather just have some key to post to the user's wall), and then do the post at some later time.

I'm unable to find the documentation for how to do this at the facebook developer site and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for `publish_stream` permissions then post to that user's wall using your "app" access token if the user access token has expired.

Facebook documentation here:   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> **publish_stream**
>
> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   **you can publish content to a user's feed at any time**. However, please
>   note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

Comment: right, but who is "that user"? I have an app to which many people will subscribe.  Then at some point in the future I wish to post a specific thing to a specific user's wall... where is this association stored?

Comment: Facebook keeps track of the associations between apps and users.  If you know they are an app user, then HTTP POST the `/USER_ID/feed`.

Comment: where would I get their USER_ID? When they sign up for my app, they type their info into the Facebook api window (this is in Android), so, I don't have visibility into that text input.  Is this a data field that I can pull from their JSON after they've logged in? And if so, you're saying I should store their user_id in my database and then use the http call to post at a later time?

Comment: When you've authenticated the user (irregardless of the API's SDK) you will get the facebook user id. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461150/android-and-facebook-how-to-get-picture-of-logged-in-user for information on how to get the ID of the current user.