# facebook How to get all photo of logged in User?

Tags: android, facebook

I create app to Facebook with `facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0`

How to get all photo of logged in User?

I need to load  user all photo

I use [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample) code

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461150/android-and-facebook-how-to-get-picture-of-logged-in-user)

I have to use [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo)

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{photo-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

please help 
please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get everyone's Facebook profile picture using below.

You just call http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_USERID/picture?type=large. This URL redirects you to image URL.

extention onto my answer:

**how do I get the entire album?**

You need https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/albums?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN] to get JSON array of all the albums of a user.

You will get three important things from here id - album id, name - album name, and type - album type.

**What permissions do I need?**

The permission required is user_photos see here

What is the best way to get ALL profile pictures from a given user?
Profile Pictures are under "Profile Pictures" album. To get to profile album, you need to look into albums array (as mentioned previously), iterate through the JSON result-set, until you get an album with name = Profile Pictures and type = profile. Get id of this object. This is the profile pictures album.

Now you can access it similar to you access any other album. That is, https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUM_ID]/photos?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN] this will list all the profile pictures of the user ever uploaded.

Hope this helps.

refer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I get prolile picture. how can I get all photos user's albums?

Comment: edited my answer i have gave you the call and the permission and links to external documents. @toni7777